# unable to append dropdown's selected text to a table cell value

Tags: javascript, html

i have a table with a header row and a drop down with three options. I want to append the selected option's text/value of drop down to the header row value of table. Please help on how can i accomplish this task.

Example: if first option of drop down is "First", and table header row value has "This is header", I want to append this "First" to "This is header" and show it as "This is header first"

```
[DEMO][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/nocw3478/
```

Comment: You should use onChange and then wrap your logic to a function

Comment: You better write the code here so people can understand the context without going to other link

Comment: @ahfa, can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Good attempt. As others have noted, you need an on-change listener.  Here's one I put together for you, it's not perfect, but it will help you get started. Replace all your JavaScript in your example with this:

```js
var original_header_text = document.querySelector('#headerText').innerText;
document.querySelector('#myOptions').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var selected = {
    'text': event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].text
  };
  document.querySelector('#headerText').innerText = original_header_text + selected.text;
});
```

Comment: ,thank you. But I have query. After replacing the code and modifying it a bit, i am able to append the selected dropdown text to table header row. Now, if i select "first" from drop down, it is getting appended to table header cell value("This is headerFirst"), but if i change it to second option, it is showing as "This is headerFirstSecond" which is not expected. I want only "This is headerSecond". How to do this?

Comment: Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/zefatx6h/     , If i select "First" it is getting appended to table header value "This is headerFirst" which is working as expected. But if i change dropdown from "First" to "Second", then the table header row is "This is headerFirstSecond", and same happening when selected as third("This is headerFirstSecondThird")

Comment: Your code changed `[selected.index]` to `[0]`. The `[0]` is always targeting the first `<tr>` of the table which is why it keeps appending text to the first row. What is the result that you want?

Comment: I misread your previous comment. I updated the code in my answer with one that works per your comments.